# L1 Cache Storage on GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu, cpu-cache, gpu-shared-memory

GPUs with compute capability 2.x organize their on-chip memory into 32 banks. The on-chip memory can be used with 2 configurations: 48 KB shared and 16 KB L1 or vice versa. For the 48 KB shared and 16 KB L1 configuration, on which memory banks is the L1 cache stored. As I understand shared memory storage, when writing to it, successive 32 bit words are stored on successive banks. This makes me think that for the 48 KB shared and 16 KB L1 configuration, each memory bank will store 384 32-bit words for shared memory and 128 32-bit words for L1 cache. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correclty: you are asking if e.g. bank0 holds addresses shifted relatively to 0 by 32, 64 etc 4-byte words (i.e. by 128Bytes), so that e.g. `p[0]` and `p[32]` (`int* p`) correspond to the same bank, correct?

Such organization is, I believe, implied by section F.4.3 (Shared Memory) of Programming Guide (5.0), in particular by part on "32-Strided Access".

Some visualization of this orgranization is also provided on page 84 of [this presentation](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.download.nvidia.com%2FGTC%2FPDF%2FGTC2012%2FPresentationPDF%2FS0514-GTC2012-GPU-Performance-Analysis.pdf&ei=vfRNUPHbDPP14QT2qoCwDg&usg=AFQjCNGNSS1nyVAUNDhhEjEs32gEWoHEVg&sig2=T00wgXQbJwcTgi2tRG-hDg&cad=rja). In short: you are correct, for SMEM.

Access pattern for L1 is 128Byte wide, so it holds 128 128Byte-wide lines in your configuration (and there is no relation between addresses of `N`th an `(N+1)`th line). You might interpret single 128Byte line as giving 4Bytes to each of 32 banks, and then you are correct in this part too.